# Calculating Number of Permutations in 2D Barcode

Tags: combinatorics

I want to calculate all possible combinations of a 2d barcode with 8 lines: [2d barcode with 8 lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yYS2.gif).
Each line can be either present (1) or not (0):

My approach is:

- Total number of objects (n) = 8
- Number of elements taken (r) = 2
- Repetitions are allowed

$$ 8^2 = 64$$

Am I correct?

Comment: This is a [Multiplication Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) problem.  It is neither a permutation nor a combination problem.  Problems about enumeration should be tagged combinatorics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not exactly right. For each bar, you can either choose $0$ or $1$. Since there are $8$ bars, you have $\underset{8 \text{ times}}{\underbrace{2 \times 2 \times 2 \times ... \times 2}}=2^8$ possibilities.

In general, the number of functions from $[|1,n|]$ to $[|1,k|]$ is $k^n$ (and not $n^k$)

Comment: By applications, do you mean functions?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I’ll edit my post